# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am only starting to learn ROS by attending Udemy course on it. Recently I have encountered a problem, when I try to run simple talker example using command:

```
rosrun ros_essentials_cpp talker.py
```

I receive an error:

```
    (base) ➜  catkin_ws rosrun ros_essentials_cpp talker.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/daniu/Documents/Projects/ROS/catkin_ws/src/ros_essentials_cpp/src/topic01_basics/talker_listener/scripts/talker.py", line 3, in <module>
    import rospy
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from std_msgs.msg import Header
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/std_msgs/msg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._Bool import *
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/std_msgs/msg/_Bool.py", line 5, in <module>
    import genpy
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . message import Message, SerializationError, DeserializationError, MessageException, struct_I
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 44, in <module>
    import yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

I tried to install yaml

```
python2.7 -m pip install pyyaml
```

Installation was successful, but it does not change anything

Previously I had no problems running ROS code (this talker.py too), but I have made a pause in my learning and after return, nothing is working

I am using WSL (Ubuntu 18.04 bionic)

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327808/modulenotfounderror:-no-module-named-%27yaml%27/) by [beliavskij](https://answers.ros.org/users/44008/beliavskij/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-07-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-07**:
Do you have any other Python interpreters / IDEs / runtime environments installed? Anaconda by any chance?

What is the output of `which python` and `python -c 'import yaml'`?

**Comment by [beliavskij](https://answers.ros.org/users/44008/beliavskij/) on 2019-07-07**:
Yes, I do, I have an anaconda and my default Python is Python 3

```
(base) ➜  ~ python --version
Python 3.7.1

(base) ➜  ~ which python
/home/belia/miniconda3/bin/python

(base) ➜  ~ python -c 'import yaml'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

Is it a problem in their conflict? I was thinking about it, but did't find a way to resolve this

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-08**:
Yes, having Anaconda installed and having Python 3 the default is the cause of your problems.

There are many Q&As about this on this site. I suggest you search for them using Google (append `site:answers.ros.org` to your query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, I have found a solution that helped, it is described in [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/259437/how-to-run-ros-if-your-default-python-version-is-3x-via-anaconda/?answer=323651#post-id-323651) answer
Using `souce deactivate` let my run the code
Thank you

---

Originally posted by [beliavskij](https://answers.ros.org/users/44008/beliavskij/) with karma: 26 on 2019-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1